# jQuery get an entire input element, including its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following codes:

```js
// Add a single component
$(document).on("click", ".copy-component .fa.fa-plus", function() {
    var component = $(this).closest(".one-component");
 var componentContainer = component.closest(".x_panel");

    componentContainer.append(component[0].outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-padding">
    <div class="x_panel border-true">
        <div class="x_title component-field">...</div>
        <div class="one-component">
            <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox panel-row">...
        </div>
        <div class="x_content eight no-margin-top component-container">
            <form id="demo-form" data-parsley-validate="" novalidate="">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <label class="input-upper-title">Cum. Len. (ft)</label>
                            <div class="has-checkbox">
                               <input type="checkbox"><input disabled="disabled" type="text" id="" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">...</div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">...</div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">...</div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is how it currently looks like:
[image]
As you can see, the input values were not copied.

The first row was originally there, but the second row was dynamically added by clicking "Add" button at the bottom.

When I click the icon "`+`" (`.fa.fa-plus`), I want a new component to be appended, including what's inside the input field right now.

Here's what I want:
[image]

How can I modify my jQuery code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should append [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) element instead of getting `outerHTML` and appending it.

> Create a deep copy of the set of matched elements.

```
componentContainer.append(component.clone(true));
```

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('#a').clone().appendTo('div');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add</button>
<input id="a" />
<div>

</div>
```